# Accessing ssh on Fedora 14 server not possible

Tags: ssh

After upgrading Fedora version to Fedora 14, ssh access is not working any longer.

This is the IP tables configuration:

```
[root@r2d2 ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251         state NEW udp dpt:mdns 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
[root@r2d2 ~]# ^C
```

The LAN IP address of the server is 192.168.0.99. The IF address from outside the FW is 85.30.155.156. The firewall is unchanged from before upgrading the Fedora server.

It is possible to access the server from itself:

```
[root@r2d2 ~]# ssh perelis@192.168.0.99
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.99 (192.168.0.99)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 11:45:9b:8a:78:76:14:b5:d2:54:f7:ad:d8:32:e9:33.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.99' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
perelis@192.168.0.99's password: 
Last login: Thu Apr 14 23:20:45 2011 from vader.roinge
[perelis@r2d2 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to 192.168.0.99 closed.
[root@r2d2 ~]# ssh perelis@85.30.155.156
ssh: connect to host 85.30.155.156 port 22: Connection timed out
[root@r2d2 ~]#
```

On the same network (no FW between, just a switch), I have a windows machine. I try to access the Linux server; Running telnet and ping from my windows computer:

```
    C:\Users\PerE>telnet 192.168.0.99 22
    Ansluter till 192.168.0.99...Det gick inte att ansluta till värddatorn, på porte n 22: Anslutningen misslyckades.
    C:\Users\PerE>ssh perelis@192.168.0.99
    ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.99 port 22: Connection timed out
    C:\Users\PerE>
C:\Users\PerE>ping 192.168.0.99
    Skickar ping-signal till 192.168.0.99 med 32 byte data:
    Svar från 192.168.0.99: byte=32 tid=1ms TTL=64
    Svar från 192.168.0.99: byte=32 tid=1ms TTL=64
    Svar från 192.168.0.99: byte=32 tid=1ms TTL=64
    Svar från 192.168.0.99: byte=32 tid=1ms TTL=64
    Ping-statistik för 192.168.0.99:
        Paket: Skickade = 4, Mottagna = 4, Förlorade = 0 (0 %),
    Ungefärlig överföringstid i millisekunder:
        Lägsta = 1 ms, Högsta = 1 ms, Medel = 1 ms
    C:\Users\PerE>
```

The error message is in Swedish but it states that it could not connect to the host (192.168.0.99 is the linux host)

Where am I missing out. This is so strange. Please help.

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -lnp` look like on your Fedora box?

Comment: On the server run tcpdump -i eth0 dst port 22 while you are trying to connect, post that output here.

If you do not get any output (change interface name of course)) then there is a problem going through your router

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing your iptables first.  It's got a few more rules in there than necessary, and even though it looks like it should be passing all traffic it's a good idea to take that out of the equation first.

Do you have `UseDNS no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?